# How to wrap y axis label in poi apache

Tags: excel, scala, apache-poi, bar-chart, spreadsheet

> I have created stacked bar chart in excel file using apache poi. How can I wrap y axis label without increasing width. Can anyone help with this?

```
   var filename = new Date();
      filename.toString();
      var f1 = filename.toString.replaceAll(":", "")
      var file = new File(Play.application().configuration().getString("bdc.documents.location") + "/exportedDocuments/" + f1 + ".xlsx");
      file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
      val fileOut = new FileOutputStream(file)
      val wb = new XSSFWorkbook()
      val sheet = wb.createSheet("Sheet1");
      var row = sheet.createRow(0);
      row.createCell(0).setCellValue("Requirement Name")
      row.createCell(1).setCellValue("Initial Stage")
      row.createCell(2).setCellValue("Appliaction stage")
      row.createCell(3).setCellValue("Integration Stage")
      row.createCell(4).setCellValue("Infrastructure Stage")
      row.createCell(5).setCellValue("Development Division Head")
      row.createCell(6).setCellValue("Buisness Partner Approval")
      row.createCell(7).setCellValue("Resource Allocation")
      var cnt = 0
      var requirementMap = new java.util.HashMap[String, String]();
      var initialMap = new java.util.HashMap[String, String]();
      var applicationMap = new java.util.HashMap[String, String]();
      var integrationMap = new java.util.HashMap[String, String]();
      var infrastructureMap = new java.util.HashMap[String, String]();
      var developmentMap = new java.util.HashMap[String, String]();
      var pendingMap = new java.util.HashMap[String, String]();
      var resourceMap = new java.util.HashMap[String, String]();
      if(!estimationDelays.isEmpty){
        for(e <- estimationDelays){
          cnt = cnt + 1
          var row = sheet.createRow(cnt);
          var name = e.requirement_name
          var initial = e.initial_delayed_days.get.toString() + " "
          var application = e.application_delayed_days.get.toString() + " "
          var integration = e.integration_delayed_days.get.toString() + " "
          var infrastucture = e.infrastructure_delayed_days.get.toString() + " "
          var development = e.development_delayed_days.get.toString() + " "
          var pending = e.pending_delayed_days.get.toString() + " "
          var resource = e.resource_dalayed_days.get.toString() + " "
          row.createCell(0).setCellValue(name)
          row.createCell(1).setCellValue(initial)
          row.createCell(2).setCellValue(application)
          row.createCell(3).setCellValue(integration)
          row.createCell(4).setCellValue(infrastucture)
          row.createCell(5).setCellValue(development)
          row.createCell(6).setCellValue(pending)
          row.createCell(7).setCellValue(resource)
        }
      }
       cnt = 0
      if(!estimationDelays.isEmpty){
        for(e <- estimationDelays.reverse){
          cnt = cnt + 1
          requirementMap.put(cnt.toString, e.requirement_name)
          initialMap.put(cnt.toString, e.initial_delayed_days.get.toString())
          applicationMap.put(cnt.toString, e.application_delayed_days.get.toString())
          integrationMap.put(cnt.toString, e.integration_delayed_days.get.toString())
          infrastructureMap.put(cnt.toString, e.infrastructure_delayed_days.get.toString())
          developmentMap.put(cnt.toString, e.development_delayed_days.get.toString())
          pendingMap.put(cnt.toString, e.pending_delayed_days.get.toString())
          resourceMap.put(cnt.toString, e.resource_dalayed_days.get.toString())
        }
      }

      var estimationMap = new java.util.HashMap[String, String]();         
      estimationMap.put("1", "Initial Stage")
      estimationMap.put("2", "Appliaction stage")
      estimationMap.put("3", "Integration Stage")
      estimationMap.put("4", "Infrastructure Stage")
      estimationMap.put("5", "Development Division Head")
      estimationMap.put("6", "Buisness Partner Approval")
      estimationMap.put("7", "Resource Allocation") 

      var size = estimationDelays.size
      var a = size + 3
      var b = 18
      var c = a * 4
      var a1 = 0
      var b1 = 0
      var c1 = 0

      var drawing = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
      var anchor = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 5, 0, 0, a, b, c)
      var chart = drawing.createChart(anchor)

      var ctChart = chart.getCTChart
      var ctPlotArea = ctChart.getPlotArea();
      var ctBarChart = ctPlotArea.addNewBarChart();

      var anchor1 = drawing.createAnchor(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, a1, b1, c1)
      var shape = drawing.createSimpleShape(anchor1)
      shape.setShapeType(ShapeTypes.LINE);
      shape.setLineWidth(1.5);
      shape.setLineStyle(3);
      shape.setLineStyleColor(0, 0, 255);

      var ctBoolean1 = ctBarChart.addNewVaryColors();
      ctBoolean1.setVal(false)
      ctBarChart.addNewBarDir().setVal(STBarDir.BAR);
      ctBarChart.addNewGrouping().setVal(STBarGrouping.STACKED);

      var data = 100.toByte
      ctBarChart.addNewOverlap().setVal(data)

      var dLbls = ctBarChart.addNewDLbls();
      dLbls.addNewShowBubbleSize().setVal(false);
      dLbls.addNewShowLegendKey().setVal(false);
      dLbls.addNewShowCatName().setVal(false);
      dLbls.addNewShowSerName().setVal(false);
      dLbls.addNewShowPercent().setVal(false);
      dLbls.addNewShowVal().setVal(true);

    val buisness: Array[Byte] = Array(96,189.toByte,104)
    val application: Array[Byte] = Array(93,165.toByte,218.toByte)
    val integration: Array[Byte] = Array(178.toByte,145.toByte,47)
    val infrastructure: Array[Byte] = Array(205.toByte,162.toByte,252.toByte)
    val development: Array[Byte] = Array(173.toByte,191.toByte,10)
    val resource: Array[Byte] = Array(25,101,169.toByte)

     for (r <- 1 to 7) {
         var cTBarSer = ctBarChart.addNewSer();
         var cTStrRef = cTBarSer.addNewTx().addNewStrRef();
         cTStrRef.setF("Label " + r);
         cTStrRef.addNewStrCache().addNewPtCount().setVal(1);
         var cTStrVal = cTStrRef.getStrCache().addNewPt();
         cTStrVal.setIdx(0);
         cTStrVal.setV(estimationMap.get(r.toString));

         cTBarSer.addNewIdx().setVal(r-1);  
         cTStrRef = cTBarSer.addNewCat().addNewStrRef();
         cTStrRef.setF("Categories");
         cTStrRef.addNewStrCache().addNewPtCount().setVal(3);
         for (c <- 1 to size + 1) {
          cTStrVal = cTStrRef.getStrCache().addNewPt();
          cTStrVal.setIdx(c-1);
          cTStrVal.setV(requirementMap.get(c.toString));
         }

         var cTNumRef = cTBarSer.addNewVal().addNewNumRef();
         cTNumRef.setF("" + r);
         cTNumRef.addNewNumCache().addNewPtCount().setVal(3);
         for (c <- 1 to size + 1) {
          var cTNumVal = cTNumRef.getNumCache().addNewPt();
          cTNumVal.setIdx(c-1);
          if (r == 1) {         
            cTNumVal.setV(initialMap.get(c.toString))     
            var ctShapeProperties = cTBarSer.addNewSpPr();
            ctShapeProperties.addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(buisness);
          } else {
            if (r == 2) {                 
              cTNumVal.setV(applicationMap.get(c.toString))
              var ctShapeProperties = cTBarSer.addNewSpPr();
              ctShapeProperties.addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(application);
            } else {
              if (r == 3) {                    
                cTNumVal.setV(integrationMap.get(c.toString))
                var ctShapeProperties = cTBarSer.addNewSpPr();
                ctShapeProperties.addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(integration);
              } else {
                if (r == 4) {                      
                  cTNumVal.setV(infrastructureMap.get(c.toString))
                  var ctShapeProperties = cTBarSer.addNewSpPr();
                  ctShapeProperties.addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(infrastructure);
                } else {
                  if (r == 5) {                       
                    cTNumVal.setV(developmentMap.get(c.toString))
                    var ctShapeProperties = cTBarSer.addNewSpPr();
                    ctShapeProperties.addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(development);
                  } else {
                    if (r == 6) {                          
                      cTNumVal.setV(pendingMap.get(c.toString))
                      var ctShapeProperties = cTBarSer.addNewSpPr();
                      ctShapeProperties.addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(buisness);
                    } else {
                      if (r == 7) {                            
                        cTNumVal.setV(resourceMap.get(c.toString))
                        var ctShapeProperties = cTBarSer.addNewSpPr();
                        ctShapeProperties.addNewSolidFill().addNewSrgbClr().setVal(resource);
                      } else {

                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
         }
     }

    ctBarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123456);
    ctBarChart.addNewAxId().setVal(123457);

    //cat axis
    var ctCatAx = ctPlotArea.addNewCatAx();
    ctCatAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123456); //id of the cat axis
    var ctScaling = ctCatAx.addNewScaling();
    ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
    ctCatAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
    ctCatAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.B);
    ctCatAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123457); //id of the val axis
    ctCatAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);

    //val axis
    val ctValAx = ctPlotArea.addNewValAx();
    ctValAx.addNewAxId().setVal(123457); //id of the val axis
    ctScaling = ctValAx.addNewScaling();
    ctScaling.addNewOrientation().setVal(STOrientation.MIN_MAX);
    ctScaling.addNewMin().setVal(0)
    ctScaling.addNewMax().setVal(550)
    ctValAx.addNewDelete().setVal(false);
    ctValAx.addNewAxPos().setVal(STAxPos.L);
    ctValAx.addNewCrossAx().setVal(123456); //id of the cat axis          
    ctValAx.addNewTickLblPos().setVal(STTickLblPos.NEXT_TO);


    //legend
    val ctLegend = ctChart.addNewLegend();
    ctLegend.addNewLegendPos().setVal(STLegendPos.T);
    ctLegend.addNewOverlay().setVal(false);

      wb.write(fileOut)
```

> I have created stacked bar chart in excel file using apache poi. How can I wrap y axis label without increasing width. Can anyone help with this?Can anyone help with this? [stacked bar chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjvZx.png)

Comment: The code is too long, you need to simplify it so that your question can be easily understood.  Try adding your code in a pseudo-code, and point out the issue that you have attempted to resolve.  What have you tried? We will try our best to point you in the right direction.  Read this for improving your question, https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: At first: Your code is not `Java`. What is it? But what you wants is not possible since there are not settings for axis labels to achieve this. The line feed must be contained in the label text. So in `cTStrVal.setV(requirementMap.get(c.toString));` the `requirementMap.get(c.toString)` must contain the "\n" already.

Comment: Thanks it worked :)

Comment: @ankita lembhe: You should avoiding tagging somewhat `java` what is not `Java`. Maybe your code is `Scala`? If so, do tagging it `scala` and not `java`. Else you will get downvoted since you are confusing the audience.

Comment: yes it is Scala, It was suggesting me for java, so I ignored to add scala.....I've updated it. :)

Comment: One more question related with this chart only "Stacked bar chart" - how can I hide only 0 values which is showing on bar.

Comment: Cannot test this but should be `var dLblsNumFmt = dLbls.addNewNumFmt(); dLblsNumFmt.setSourceLinked(false); dLblsNumFmt.setFormatCode("#.##0;\\-#.##0;");`. See [CTDLbls.addNewNumFmt](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTDLbls.java#CTDLbls.addNewNumFmt%28%29) -> [CTNumFmt](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.poi/ooxml-schemas/1.1/org/openxmlformats/schemas/drawingml/x2006/chart/CTNumFmt.java#CTNumFmt).

Comment: That's great it worked ...!!! I just used dLblsNumFmt.setFormatCode("#;\\-#;"); for Integer only. Thanks Axel :)

Answer (score 2):

> woking... with adding "\n" in label name